# Communication between Vue root and any child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a series of components that go several levels deep. Each component has its own piece of data that it loads over AJAX and uses to render each instance of child components. The `days` parent template for example:

```
<template>
    <accordion :one-at-atime="true" type="info">
        <panel :is-open="index === 0" type="primary" :header="'Day ' + day.day" v-for="(day, index) in days" :key="day.id">
            <br/>
            <div class="panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Cycles</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                        <cycles
                            :day="day"
                        >
                        </cycles>
                </div>
            </div>
        </panel>
    </accordion>
</template>
```

The `cycles` child template for example:

```
<template>
    <accordion :one-at-atime="true" type="info">
        <panel :is-open="index === 0" type="primary" :header="'Week ' + cycle.week + ': ' + cycle.name" v-for="(cycle, index) in cycles" :key="cycle.id">
            <form v-on:submit.prevent="update">
                ....misc input fields here...
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" v-if="cycle.id" v-on:click="destroy">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </panel>
    </accordion>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'day'
        ],
        data() {
            return {
                cycles: []
            }
        },
        beforeMount: function () {
            var self = this;

            if (this.cycles.length === 0) {
                axios.get('/plans/days/' + this.day.id + '/cycles')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        self.cycles = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
        },
        methods: {
            destroy: function (event) {
                var self = this;

                axios.delete('/plans/cycles/' + event.target.elements.id.value)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        self.cycles.filter(function (model) {
                            return model.id !== response.data.model.id;
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Each `cycles` component then renders another component in a `v-for` loop, which renders another type of component, and so on and so forth. What is created is a tree like structure of components.

When I need to send a generic request to the server that then updates the data in the component it is called from, I don't want to have to duplicate that request method in every component. I'd rather just have one instance of the method on the root Vue instance.

For example, this would be preferred:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    created: function () {
        this.$on('destroy', function (event, type, model, model_id, parent_id) {
            this.destroy(event, type, model, model_id, parent_id);
        })
    },
    methods: {
        destroy: function (event, type, model, model_id, parent_id) {
            var self = this;

            axios.delete('/plans/' + type + '/' + model_id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    model = model.filter(function (model) {
                        return model.id !== response.data.model.id;
                    });

                    this.$emit('modified-' + type + '-' + parent_id, model);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Then in the `cycles.vue` delete button call this on click:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" v-if="cycle.id" v-on:click="$root.$emit('destroy', event, 'cycles', cycles, cycle.id, day.id)">Delete</button>
```

And add this to `cycles.vue` events:

```
    created: function () {
        this.$on('modified-cycles-' + this.day.id, function (cycles) {
            this.cycles = cycles;
        })
    },
```

However, that doesn't work because the child element never gets the emitted `'modified-' + type + '-' + parent_id` event from root.

I also tried `this.$children.$emit('modified-' + type + '-' + parent_id, model);` but that didn't work either.

What's the Vue 2.5.16 way to do this? And is there a better design pattern than I am currently using?

Comment: Have you looked at Vuex? https://vuex.vuejs.org

Comment: I'm using Vuex in this project, but I don't know how to get it to work in this use case.

Comment: Do you want to include `this` in the payload of the `emit`?

Comment: @RoyJ what would be the advantage of that?

Comment: It would make the component that emitted the event available to have its data updated by the root instance.

Comment: Each Vue instance (root and children) is an event hub. You $emit events on an instance and you can subscribe to event notifications with $on on the same instance. You can use this.$root.$on() and this.$root.$emit() to achieve your purpose. However, it's not very clear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: @RoyJ I tried this but the original instance still isn't updated. `this.$root.$emit('destroy', this, event, 'cycles', cycle.id);` with `instance[type] = instance[type].filter(...);` in root which I expected to modify `instance['cycles']`.

Answer (score 2):

Each Vue instance (root and children) is an independent event hub.

You $emit events on an instance and you can subscribe to event notifications with $on **on the same instance**.

You can use `this.$root.$on()` and `this.$root.$emit()` to use the root instance as an event bus and achieve your purpose.

However, it's not very clear to me what separation of concerns you are trying to get, so I'm not ready to give better advice.

Comment: I want to keep my code DRY. By placing these common methods in the root, I need only one of them and all sub-components can re-use them.

Comment: as a general rule, each component should be responsible to maintain (i.e. assign to) the part of the state that it contains (it's own data members). In your example it seems that the action is initiated in cycles.vue and ends up changing this.cycles inside that same component: why would you involve any other component at all? One thing you could do is abstract away API calls into a separate module that you import and use from all components.